# aws sdk c++ code don't work on release build

Tags: c++, dll, aws-sdk-cpp, release-builds

I have a .dll c++ project created in visual studio 2017. And I have code in it that uses aws sdk to get files from s3 bucket.

I built this dll project on Debug mode mode and uses it on my main application (c++ also). And it worked.

Now i did make a release build of both dll project and my main application. And my application crashes when executing the "aws sdk c++" code.

Here's the code snippet about aws sdk c++:

```
    int Download()
    {
        Aws::SDKOptions options;
        Aws::InitAPI(options);
        {
            const Aws::String bucket_name = "timestamp-storage";
            //Aws::String key_name = "";
            const Aws::String region = "ap-northeast-1";
            std::map<int, std::string> uploadedBioMap = BiometricDB::List();
            std::map<int, std::string>::iterator i;
            for (i = uploadedBioMap.begin(); i != uploadedBioMap.end(); i++) {
                Aws::String key_name = i->second;
                std::cout << "Downloading " << key_name << " from S3 bucket: " <<
                    bucket_name << std::endl;
                Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
                if (!region.empty())
                    clientConfig.region = region;
                Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(clientConfig);
                Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
                object_request.WithBucket(bucket_name).WithKey(key_name);
                auto get_object_outcome = s3_client.GetObject(object_request);
                if (get_object_outcome.IsSuccess())
                {
                    Aws::OFStream local_file;
                    local_file.open(("enroll/" + key_name).c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
                    local_file << get_object_outcome.GetResult().GetBody().rdbuf();
                    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "GetObject error: " <<
                        get_object_outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
                        get_object_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
        return 1;
    }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: If something works in a debug build but crashes in release (or works in release but crash in debug) it's typically a sign of *undefined behavior*. If you build a "release" version with debug information, does it crash as well? And if so, can you enter a debugger when the crash happens to locate it, and examine the involved variabled at that point?

Comment: just making a guess here :  do you have the aws c++ sdk libraries built in 'release mode'? Probably the libraries/dependencies are built in debug mode so they work in debug mode so the release mode build of the libraries will be needed to make it work in release mode.

Comment: I debug the released build and it shows the file that has an error, the "iosfwd" file with the exception thrown message about (vcruntime140.dll): Access violation writing location

Comment: Where in ***your*** code does the crash happen? Please walk up the function call stack until you're are your code.

Comment: It stop after it execute this line of code "clientConfig.region = region;". I think that's where the error occur.

Comment: That line of code is in the code snippet that I posted above.

Comment: You say it reports an access violation; does it give an address for the location it tries to write to?

Comment: Thank you guys for responding me.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, nothings wrong with my code. I just found out that I need to update the nuget packages that I installed in visual studio. And so when i did, it solves the problem. Thank you.