# AWS Lambda C++: Works in Debug Mode, not in Release

Tags: c++, aws-lambda

I've come bearing a question. Learning AWS, and I want to call some Lambda functions from a local computer in C++. The code below works great in Debug mode, not a problem, but in Release, not so much.

The code fails in multiple places, but I'm hoping they are the same issue. Here's what I'm attempting to do below (essentially the beginning of the Invoke Function example from AWS Lambda for C++, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cpp_1_lambda_code_examples.html):

```
#define USE_IMPORT_EXPORT
#define USE_WINDOWS_DLL_SEMANTICS

#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>
#include <aws/lambda/LambdaClient.h>
#include <aws/lambda/model/ListFunctionsRequest.h>
#include <aws/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.h>
#include <aws/lambda/model/LogType.h>

int main() {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);

    // Setup credentials
    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
    credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("id");
    credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("secret");

    // Setup config
    Aws::Client::ClientConfigurationInitValues values;
    values.shouldDisableIMDS = true;
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig(values);
    clientConfig.region = "us-east-2"; // xstring's Memmove failure
    Aws::Lambda::LambdaClient client(credentials, clientConfig); // aws Optional.h copy failure
}
```

When attempting to override the region, I get an error from xstring's memmove: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p2o4.png)

And when skipping that and attempting to create the client, I get an error from aws\crt\Optional.h: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiIZP.png)

Even for a short example, there's a lot of moving parts, so I wouldn't surprised if I missed anything. So far, I can't find a difference in the two configurations, and I just put the needed .dlls and .libs in pretty much any and every folder. I also tried different C++ Language versions, but to no avail.

I'll keep on banging my head into this nice, wooden wall, but in the meantime, if anyone knows what is up or needs any more information, give me a holler!

Appreciate it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, Sam! Unfortunately, there's not much more code I can provide, but I added the rest of the function and the header information. This is essentially a copy of the beginning of AWS's Invoke Function example for Lambda in C++ (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cpp_1_lambda_code_examples.html). The above code should compile, however, as long as the headers/libraries are built somewhere and linked to. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide!

Answer (score -1):

This looks like it is an issue with the sdk client libraries.
You can use the CMake variable "AWSSDK_CLIENT_LIBS" to compare debug and release versions of the client libraries.

Comment: Hi Steve! Thank you for taking the time to help me out. You actually caught something I forgot to do, which is I didn't build a release configuration of the sdk client libraries. Having done that now, I was hoping that this was my error, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same memmove problem. I'm not very avid in CMake; how should I be using the CMake variable to compare the versions? Is there a command I can run that I could pass this as a flag?

Comment: (I also realized I could try updating the code again since the configuration is now correct, as per this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157624/aws-sdk-c-code-dont-work-on-release-build. Will update this thread on those results as well.)

Comment: Alright, I did all of that, but I'm still running into the same issue. I'll be reaching out to other people now to try to resolve this.

Comment: You building on Windows and copying dynamic libraries to your executable folder. It is important that you are copying the same dynamic libraries that the SDK is linking against.